# Unable to get the right SUM using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have been trying to get the `TotalCharge` , `TotalCost` and `Total Estimated hours`.

Although there are no errors in my script but some how I couldn't get the total of above columns.

My script is below:

```
SELECT
  l.LaborName,
  l.EstimatedHours,
  l.TotalCost,
  l.TotalCharge,
  w.CurrencySymbol,
  SUM(l.TotalCost) AS totalCost,
  SUM(l.TotalCharge) AS totalCharge,
  SUM(l.EstimatedHours) AS totalHours
FROM WOLabor l
INNER JOIN WO w
  ON l.WOPK = w.WOPK
WHERE l.WOPK = 10100
AND RecordType = 1
GROUP BY l.LaborName,
         l.EstimatedHours,
         l.TotalCost,
         l.TotalCharge,
         w.CurrencySymbol
```

and here is my output:

[image]

my expected output is 
[image]

Comment: @Abhishek Please check the screenshot of output . totalCost , totalCharge and totalHours should be 18,39.90 and 2

Comment: please check your data, how would they be grouped together if the data is distinct - have a look on the LaborName.

Comment: For that exact output, you could easily do a summation row in a reporting tool like SSRS (a part of Visual Studio using Data Tools) or in PowerBI with it's automatic totals summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didnt accepted noone of given answers, i guess you are looking for the "whole data" sum, so you should just remove the `LaborName` and `EstimatedHours` from your select and group by

```
SELECT
  l.LaborName,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, l.EstimatedHours) [EstimatedHours],
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, l.TotalCost) TotalCost,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, l.TotalCharge) TotalCharge
FROM WOLabor l
INNER JOIN WO w
  ON l.WOPK = w.WOPK
WHERE l.WOPK = 10100
AND RecordType = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'Estimated Labor Totals',
  SUM(l.EstimatedHours) AS totalHours,
  --CONCAT(W.CURRENCYSYMBOL, ' ', CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SUM(L.TOTALCOST))),
  --CONCAT(W.CURRENCYSYMBOL, ' ', CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SUM(L.TOTALCHARGE))) 
  W.CURRENCYSYMBOL + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SUM(L.TOTALCOST)),
  W.CURRENCYSYMBOL + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SUM(L.TOTALCHARGE))     
FROM WOLabor l
INNER JOIN WO w
  ON l.WOPK = w.WOPK
WHERE l.WOPK = 10100
AND RecordType = 1
GROUP BY W.CURRENCYSYMBOL
```

[sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/71924/1)

Output:

```
LaborName               EstimatedHours  TotalCost   TotalCharge
Barnes, Ashley          1               9           9.9
Chelsea, Smith          1               9           30
Estimated Labor Totals  2               Mex$ 18     Mex$ 39.9
```

Comment: i have added my expected output

Comment: i am applying your script to my sql server 2014 but still getting error
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.'

Comment: what do you mean for "getting error" ? is that unexpected output or not working query? As you can check in Sql Fiddle it is working with sample data

Comment: query is not working . 
error message is : 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: from Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014): it should work in sql server 2014. Anyway i edited the answer replacing the concat function with an implicit concat (using `+` between nvarchar values)

Comment: i have solved the problem . i have used Convert function instead of CONCAT. Thnak you for your help .

Comment: well im happy you solved it, but pay attention to functions: `CONVERT` and `CONCAT` arent supposed to be used for the same reason so how did you switched them? More, if this helped you solve your problem please consider accepting it as answer.

Comment: please check the below two lines what i have used

`CONVERT(nvarchar(max), W.CURRENCYSYMBOL, 22) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SUM(L.TOTALCOST)),
   CONVERT(nvarchar(max), W.CURRENCYSYMBOL, 22) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SUM(L.TOTALCHARGE))`

Comment: but the CONCAT function should work because i am using sql server 2014 . noted your comment and i will definitely read about CONCAT and convert function . thank you once again

Answer (score 3):

You are grouping by the columns you only need the sum of. 
 Remove them from the `GROUP BY`:

```
 SELECT
      l.LaborName,
      w.CurrencySymbol,
      SUM(l.TotalCost) AS totalCost,
      SUM(l.TotalCharge) AS totalCharge,
      SUM(l.EstimatedHours) AS totalHours
    FROM WOLabor l
    INNER JOIN WO w
      ON l.WOPK = w.WOPK
    WHERE l.WOPK = 10100
    AND RecordType = 1
    GROUP BY l.LaborName,
             w.CurrencySymbol
```

Comment: dear Rigerta Demiri it is still not working . actually i want to get all the columns plus sum of three .  so remove some field from select list is not a very good option

Comment: I understand, then the window function is what you need. The answer by @Yogesh Sharma

Answer (score 2):

You seems to want *window* function :

```
SELECT distinct l.LaborName, l.EstimatedHours, l.TotalCost,
       l.TotalCharge, w.CurrencySymbol,
       SUM(l.TotalCost) over (partition by l.LaborName, w.CurrencySymbol) AS totalCost,
       SUM(l.TotalCharge) over (partition by l.LaborName, w.CurrencySymbol) AS totalCharge,
       SUM(l.EstimatedHours) over (partition by l.LaborName, w.CurrencySymbol) AS totalHours
FROM WOLabor l INNER JOIN 
     WO w
     ON l.WOPK = w.WOPK
WHERE l.WOPK = 10100 AND RecordType = 1;
```

I suspect you need `overall sum`, if so then remove `partition` clause

```
SELECT . . .
       SUM(l.TotalCost) over () AS totalCost,
       SUM(l.TotalCharge) over () AS totalCharge,
       SUM(l.EstimatedHours) over () AS totalHours
FROM WOLabor l INNER JOIN 
     WO w
     ON l.WOPK = w.WOPK
WHERE l.WOPK = 10100 AND RecordType = 1;
```

Comment: above window function also not working . the output is same as group by .

Comment: i have got the result but the total appearing two times . suppose estimated hours total is 2 then it is showing output 2 for each row . i would want to have the total estimated hours . example : 5 row and total is 6 then the output should be 6 . not output 6 against 6 rows .